# How to access a Laravel API route?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I just created a fresh Laravel project in my localhost directory and created a Laravel route in the **api.php** file.

```
Route::post('/home', 'HomeAPI@index');
```

However, when I try to send a post request to the link `localhost/home` from **Postman**, it gives the following error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

How do I access my `/home` route?

Comment: Shouldn't the route be localhost/<appname>/home?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When trying to access a API route (route mentioned in api.php) from Laravel, just add /api to the link you are trying to access. In this case, your link would be:

> localhost/api/home

This should solve your problem.

Comment: The prefix is defined in `RouteServiceProvider::mapApiRoutes()`.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in `api.php` is under `/api` so in your case it's `localhost/api/home`